Which sort of UB do I have here, deleting array of operator new[]?
Given the following code involving operator new[] and the various wrong versions of delete:
#include <iostream>

class Test {
public:
    Test()  { std::cout << "Test()\n";  }
    ~Test() { std::cout << "~Test()\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    void* p = operator new[](10 * sizeof(Test));
    Test* test = new (p) Test();
    test->~Test();
    // delete p; // UB1
    // delete[] p; // UB2
    // delete[] test; // UB3
    // operator delete[](test); // UB4?
    operator delete[](p);
    std::cout << "End\n";
}


live on https://godbolt.org/z/zG3nfzsv6
Could you please explain why UB2 through UB4 are Undefined Behavior, with some layman's term explanation of the standardese of C++20 draft N4861, §7.6.2.8 [expr.delete] and maybe §7.6.2.7 [expr.new]?
Here's my try. I'm quite confident about UB1, but not very confident about UB2 and UB3, even less about UB4.
UB1
(Emphasis mine)
§ 7.6.2.8 (1)

delete-expression:
::opt delete cast-expression
::opt delete [ ] cast-expression


The first alternative is a single-object delete expression, and the second is an array delete expression.

§ 7.6.2.8 (2)

In a single-object delete expression, the value of the operand of delete may be a null pointer value, a pointer to a non-array object created by a previous new-expression, or a pointer to a subobject (6.7.2) representing a base class of such an object (11.7). If not, the behavior is undefined.

So, for delete without [] I must not use an array pointer. But I did, so I have UB. Fine.
UB2 to UB4
(Emphasis mine)

In an array delete
expression, the value of the operand of delete may be a null pointer value or a pointer value that resulted
from a previous array new-expression.74 If not, the behavior is undefined.

Well, I have an array from a previous new expression.

[Note: This means that the syntax of the delete-expression must match the type of the object allocated by new, not the syntax of the new-expression. — end note]

Side question: Why does it mean that?
Okay, so I have operator new[] and this note tells me, that the syntax of my delete may be different. I do not necessarily need operator delete[] but something that matches the type of the object.
Side question: What is the type of my object? My pointer p is void*, but void is not an object type. Does p point to a void[] and void[] is an object type?
§ 7.6.2.8 (11)

For an array delete expression, the
deleted object is the array object. When a delete-expression is executed, the selected deallocation function
shall be called with the address of the deleted object in a single-object delete expression, or the address of
the deleted object suitably adjusted for the array allocation overhead (7.6.2.7) in an array delete expression,
as its first argument.

Sorry, I don't understand anything of that. I just have a gut feeling that this might be relevant.

The delete command takes the size of the object being deleted into account, as well as calling the destructor of the object.  void has no destructor, and no size (because void is an incomplete type — it cannot be instantiated, ergo, it cannot be destructed).

@Eljay: but I somehow have to free the memory that I allocated.

My question is why allocate memory like this?  Use an RAII type that encapsulates this so you don't have to worry about it.

@NathanOliver: that's the next step. I want to create a class, put the new[] into the constructor and put the (correct) delete[] into the destructor. Then use placement new to create objects in that buffer.

So basically you want to recreate std::vector?

These might be helpful for you: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory#Uninitialized_memory_algorithms

@NathanOliver: like that. I need a std::variant in C++14. I might simply use a library, but at the same time, I want to learn how to do such stuff myself, so I try that first, then find out how bad I am with C++ and then pick a library :-)

FWIW variant doesn't use dynamic allocation.  The objects are stored in one pool like a union.  Essentially it is just tagged (type safe) union.

Any form of delete expression has undefined behaviour if its operand is not EXACTLY equivalent to the result of a corresponding new expression.   A call of operator new() is NOT equivalent to a new expression (part of the machinery of a new expression is calling an operator new(), but other parts matter).  That explains UB1 and UB2.    A placement new expression is not equivalent to a non-placement new, which explains UB3 and UB4 (the delete expressions are being given the result of a placement new).

You need to differentiate between the new/delete expressions and the new/delete operators. They are two different things.  The operators simply allocate and free memory.  The expressions call the operators, as well as call constructors/destructors on the objects that are being created/destroyed.

new expression
delete expression
operator new, operator new[]
operator delete, operator delete[]

In your example, you are allocating raw memory using the new[] operator directly, but then UB1-UB3 are trying to free that memory using the delete expression and delete[] expression, which is wrong.
You need to match things up correctly.  Use the delete/delete[] expressions only with the new/new[] expressions 1.  Use the delete/delete[] operators only with the new/new[] operators.
1 Except in the case of your test pointer, as you can't call any form of the delete expression or operator on a pointer that is returned by placement-new, since placement-new doesn't allocate new memory, just creates an object inside existing memory. That is why you have to call the object's destructor directly in this situation.

Okay, let me try my new understanding: new expression = operator new + calling the constructor. operator new = malloc(). delete expression = calling the destructor + operator delete. operator delete = free(). Same for arrays, just multiple constructors and a larger size for malloc().

@ThomasWeller • the operator new() is like malloc(), and may be malloc() under the covers.  Or not.  My compiler has different arenas for malloc, new, and new[].  So you would have to use the matching free, delete, and delete[].  Otherwise the wrong arena heap is being accessed, and bad things happen (in my case, I call std::abort).

@ThomasWeller essentially, yes (don't forget multiple destructor calls for the delete expression of an array). Do keep in mind that users can override the new/delete operators to do different/extra things (like logging, memory pools, etc).
